# Root mean square function in R

Tags: r, function, statistics

A very brief question.
After much searching I couldn't find a function to calculate the RMS of a set of integers. Does such a function exist in R?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I didn't search for a function but you can write it

```
x <- 1:10
sqrt(sum(x^2)/length(x))
6.204837
```

A better alternative is using `mean` function

```
> sqrt(mean(x^2))
[1] 6.204837
```

Comment: You could even write a function: `RMS <- function(num) sqrt(sum(num^2)/length(num))`; `RMS(x)`

Comment: Ok thankyou...I'm not sure if it actually exists, which surprises me.

Answer (score 6):

The function `rms(x)` from the package [`{seewave}`](http://rug.mnhn.fr/seewave/HTML/MAN/rms.html) must produce the same value.

Answer (score 1):

I did a vectorized version like this (to get the rms of each row in a matrix).

```
sqrt( apply(xMat^2, 1, mean) )
```